# "RoleManager.FindByIdAsync" throws the exception : "DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

Following this tutorial about [Roles](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-roles/), I get this exception

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

that is related to this line :

```
IdentityRole role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(Role);
```

My project contains a view with an attribute that triggers a tag-helper :

```
<td i-role="@role.Id"></td>
```

Here's the part of the tag helper that causes a problem :

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        IdentityRole role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(Role);
        if (role != null)
        {
            foreach (var user in userManager.Users)
            {
                if (user != null && await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
                    names.Add(user.UserName);
            }
        }
        output.Content.SetContent(names.Count == 0 ? "No Users" : string.Join(", ", names));
    }
```

I checked with the debugger if *Role* is the correct id given and it's indeed the right id

```
IdentityRole role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(Role);
```

So I don't understand where the problem lies... Could you help me please ?

Comment: Hi @YL2120, I have tested your code and it works fine. Could you please share what operation you did, I mean what code you hit before running custom tag helper code? Your error message means you did database operation without closing the datareader before you run `ProcessAsync` method.

Comment: Hello @Rena , thanks for the feedback. I finally solved the problem by adding "MultipleActiveResultSets=true" to the database connection string. I don't know if it's possible without enabling "MultipleActiveResultSets=true".

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by adding "*MultipleActiveResultSets=true*" to the DB connection string. So if someone faces the same problem, check your db connection string.